# Need help finding a closed form for sum of combinations

Tags: summation, combinations, closed-form

I'm currently working on a problem, and I think that the key to solving it requires me to find a closed-form expression for $$\sum_{i = 0}^{(n - 1)! - 1} C(n!, i)$$ Does a closed-form expression for the above even exist? Not sure if I'm totally on the wrong track. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: For a start, What is $C(a,b)$ ? ... Might be an idea to tell us about the original problem and how you come to this expression.

Comment: I assume he means the binomial coefficient $\binom{n!}{i}$.

Comment: This would generate the sequence $$\{1,1,7,55455,3498268747362198768544861\}$$ and the next term would be $\sim 7.64 \times 10^{128}$ and the next would be $\sim 1.54 \times 10^{895}$. I  suppose a problem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not in terms of elementary functions. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+i%3D%28n-1%29%21+to+n%21+of+C%28n%21%2C+i%29